# Merge array of objects inside loop into new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Trying to create a new object, and then join all the objects from nested values from a JSON file.

The JSON data is rather large, so have taken a sample, and called it var items

Problem I am having is that the nested data is not updating the new object.

```
var items = [
    {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "Fruit Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Fruit order for 1 person",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Melon",
            "otherName": "Watermelon"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Apple",
            "otherName": "Red apple"
        }
    ]

},
{
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Canned Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Canned order for 2 people",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Tomatoes",
            "otherName": "Diced tomato"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 13,
    "title": "Dairy Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Dairy Order for 2 people",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": []
}
]
;

var copyItems = [];


for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
items[i].allItems = items[i].items;
  copyItems.push(items[i])
}

console.log(copyItems);


var copyItems = copyItems.map(function(elem){
    return elem.allItems;
}).join(",");

console.log(`These are the final items ${copyItems}`);
```

I am able to create the new object, and add the nested arrays to this. However I am trying to get the allItems object to display the information like the following:

```
[
    {
    "id": 11,
    "allItems": "Melon, Apple",
    "title": "Fruit Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Fruit order for 1 person",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Melon",
            "otherName": "Watermelon"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Apple",
            "otherName": "Red apple"
        }
    ]

},
{
    "id": 12,
    "allItems": "Tomatoes",
    "title": "Canned Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Canned order for 2 people",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Tomatoes",
            "otherName": "Diced tomato"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 13,
    "allItems": "",
    "title": "Dairy Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Dairy Order for 2 people",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": []
}
]
```

Here is my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/buogdvx9/6/

Javascript is still a language I am learning and working through, and some things still catch me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Clarify, please, which output do you expect. Some examples would be nice.

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output is. Your code seems to aim for **one** string output, listing all item names. But then you provide us with a an array of objects which has the additional property. Not clear which of the two you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the new array, then using some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to create each new element in this array.

We create the allitems property on each new element by first mapping the sub items array to get a list of subitem names, then using [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a comma separated string.

The [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you see as the first argument to Array.map is another way of writing function(args) { .. }.

```js
const items = [ { "id": 11, "title": "Fruit Test", "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30", "mainContent": "Fruit order for 1 person", "storeNames": [ "Store 1" ], "items": [ { "itemName": "Melon", "otherName": "Watermelon" }, { "itemName": "Apple", "otherName": "Red apple" } ]  }, { "id": 12, "title": "Canned Test", "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30", "mainContent": "Canned order for 2 people", "storeNames": [ "Store 1" ], "items": [ { "itemName": "Tomatoes", "otherName": "Diced tomato" } ] }, { "id": 13, "title": "Dairy Test", "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30", "mainContent": "Dairy Order for 2 people", "storeNames": [ "Store 1" ], "items": [] } ];

const result = items.map(({ id, ...rest}) => { 
    return { 
      id,
      allItems: rest.items.map(el => el.itemName).join(', '), 
      ...rest
    };
});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This is exactly what I was after. This may be asking too much, but because I am still learning, the arrow in JS is still a little hard for me to follow. Is it possible to break it down so I can learn how you came to the outcome? And try the same with other examples I create? Your help has been very much appreciated either way.

Comment: Oh yes surely. I will update the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to update the existing object, using `forEach` to loop over each item in array, then loop over the prosperity with a `map` operator to get the array with itemName.

```
  items.forEach((obj) => {
      
      obj.allItems = obj.items.map((item) => item.itemName)
    });
    
    console.log(items)
```

Simple example:

```
   // iterating over the items
 for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  
    let currentItem = items[i];
  
    currentItem.allItems = []; // adding new empty array
  
    for (let j = 0; j < currentItem.items.length; j++) {
      
        currentItem.allItems.push(currentItem.items[j].itemName);
    }

}
```

Working Example:

```js
var items = [
    {
    "id": 11,
    "title": "Fruit Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Fruit order for 1 person",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Melon",
            "otherName": "Watermelon"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Apple",
            "otherName": "Red apple"
        }
    ]

},
{
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Canned Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Canned order for 2 people",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "itemName": "Tomatoes",
            "otherName": "Diced tomato"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 13,
    "title": "Dairy Test",
    "releaseDateTime": "2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30",
    "mainContent": "Dairy Order for 2 people",
    "storeNames": [
        "Store 1"
    ],
    "items": []
}
]
;
// since you only want to update the existing object, using map to loop over each item in array
items.forEach((obj) => {
  // using map to create the new array of just itemNames
  obj.allItems = obj.items.map((item) => item.itemName)
});

console.log(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the combination of `Array.map` and `Array.join`

**Logic**

- Since you want to create a new array, run `Array.map` on the parent array.
- On each nodes in the parent return the whole node with one extra key `allItems`.
- For `allItems` create a new array from `items` array in each node and join then with space

```js
var items = [{"id":11,"title":"Fruit Test","releaseDateTime":"2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30","mainContent":"Fruit order for 1 person","storeNames":["Store 1"],"items":[{"itemName":"Melon","otherName":"Watermelon"},{"itemName":"Apple","otherName":"Red apple"}]},{"id":12,"title":"Canned Test","releaseDateTime":"2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30","mainContent":"Canned order for 2 people","storeNames":["Store 1"],"items":[{"itemName":"Tomatoes","otherName":"Diced tomato"}]},{"id":13,"title":"Dairy Test","releaseDateTime":"2021-10-21T10:50:00+09:30","mainContent":"Dairy Order for 2 people","storeNames":["Store 1"],"items":[]}];
const newItems = items.map(node => ({ ...node, allItems: node.items.map(item => item.itemName).join(" ")}));
console.log(newItems);
```